# Sophos Enterprise Console 4.5, Mac Client 7 Not Auto-Populating SEC Info

Tags: anti-virus, sophos

I have Sophos Endpoint Security and Control, which includes Sophos Enterprise Console (SEC). I'm currently running version 4.5 of SEC, which is an older version. I subscribe to Mac updates, and SEC generates a binary Mac installer for me to use on Mac endpoints (Version 7 for Mac, also an older version). However, when I run the installer on Mac endpoints, it installs fine but then never auto-fills out the location of the update server, which is on a network share, and the account credentials used to access it, which I do not know and were generated by Sophos automatically.

Previously, I had been able to use the SEC-generated installer to install and run Sophos on a Mac seamlessly; the update location information and account credentials were automatically filled during login, I ran the installer and it was perfectly set up.

Now, however, Sophos installs on a Mac but never updates because it doesn't have the update location OR credentials. Has anyone else run across this problem or know why it is happening?

Sophos Enterprise Console 4.5.1.0

Comment: Ummm, you have a Sophos support contract. Probably should call them?

Comment: My organization didn't buy support.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is because your machines were left in the *Unassigned* group, which receives no policies (eg Updating). Make sure that the machine is assigned to a group and has a policy status *Same as policy*.

You can add a copy of the `com.sophos.sau.plist` file to the package (in `Contents/Packages/SophosAU.mpkg/Contents/Resources`), which you can obtain from any Mac that does have an updating policy already (in `/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus`). That will "pre-populate" the update location & credentials before the endpoint communicates with the Enterprise Console.

Also FWIW, all Sophos endpoint licenses include standard 24/7/365 support via telephone and email.